# How to load a large image before anything in the browser is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, image

The website I'm making has a large image fading in from black when the website loads. It's a good quality image and the effect turns out nice.

The problem is that when a person visits the website a first time, the fade doesn't occur and the image just appears.  I figure that the opacity is changed right away, but the image itself hasn't been downloaded. Once it's cached, revisiting the site shows the effect.

What are some ways to ensure that the image is fully downloaded before the fade in begins (the fade is simple jQuery: `$('#bg').fadeIn(1000);`)?

**EDIT** - Thank you everyone. It's been solved. I left something out that I didn't realize was important. It wasn't an `img` tag, but a `div` with an image background. When I changed it to an img, the `$(document).ready()` function loaded the image before the fade. Thank you!

Comment: I was reading in the http://api.jquery.com/ready/ comments and noticed someone mentioning that if you need the properties of a loaded element that you should use `load()` instead of `ready()`. I haven't tried this myself but figured I'd pass it on anyway (just in case!)

edit: That is, window.onload instead of document.ready!

Comment: @Gazillion yeah, I always used ready(), but load() seems much more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look at [`.load()` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in jQuery. It is called when everything in the associated element has been loaded - if you attach it to `img` tag with your image, the callback will be called when the image was fully loaded.

Comment: Though the ready() function did the trick, using load() with just the image sped it up. Thank you.

Comment: @user745434: You are welcome, but [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is called when the DOM has been constructed, even if the elements of the page (images etc.) have not been loaded. On the same page you can read: " _In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the [`load event`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead._ ".

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() { $('#bg').fadeIn(1000)) })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the Script of loading the IMG at the top of the HTML ( HEAD is in option)

**BUT**

its a bad practice.

you can maeke a basic page and  at the button scripts - you can download the img - and by the load event - you can FADE it IN.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's easier to use the ready function

http://api.jquery.com/ready/